# Internet Explorer + Windows Phone IEMobile Conditional Comments

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, windows-phone-7, conditional-comments

So I've been using these two combinations of IE conditionals:

```
<!--[if (IE)|(IEMobile)]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Do something
    </script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if (!IE)|(!IEMobile)]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Do something else
    </script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

So could such combinations work in production environment? I tried testing with IE 11 emulated to any previous version of IE and I got these results:

- The first one worked on IE for PC;
- The second one failed exposing its contents to IE for PC;
- I've not tested the IEMobile contrary because I don't have Windows Phone, so I can't be sure if some of these works on it.
  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do, but you should give feature detection a change. Instead of using browser detection.
Try http://modernizr.com/ With it you can do something like that:

```
if(Modernizr.touch){
    // Do something
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```